# How to create if-then logic in simulink?

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements, simulink

I have a written code and a program in matlab, but I want to do the same think in simulink. I am stuck at the if-then part of the program which I can't figure out.

I tried using the "If" block, but then I didn't know how to say "then alfa=0". After trying to research it I saw many different ways to do conditional statements and now I'm very confused.

```
if(vb-y(2))*y(3)<0
    alfa=0
end

if y(3)<zba && (vb-y(2))*y(3)>=0
    alfa=0
end
if zba<y(3) && y(3)<zmax && (vb-y(2))*y(3)>=0
    alfa=0.5*(sin(pi*(y(3)-(zmax+zba)/2)/(zmax-zba))+1)
end
if zmax<y(3) && (vb-y(2))*y(3)>=0
    alfa=1
end
```

I basically need this made in simulink. If someone could just start it out for me or explain the proper way to do this I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this can be done in the following way: Choose the `if-block` to implement your condition, and for the `then` and `else`-block, you choose an `if-action-block`. The if block decides which of these two if-action blocks will be evaluated at every timestep and the following `merge-block` integrates both individual outputs into one combined signal (`alfa` in your case) again. The image shows the first `if-then` of your code (assuming `else alfa=1`. In case of no else, the else-output can be disabled in the block-properties).

[image: image showing solution]
Since the `if-block` supports elseif expressions as a comma separated list, I suggest you use this for your 2nd, 3rd and 4th if's, which means that you will most likely need additional if-action blocks, and more inputs for the `merge-block`. Also for the elseif expressions, you'll need to change your `&&` to `&` which should be fine. `a && b` only evaluates b if a is true, `a & b` always evaluates both.

Comment: This seems to work, thanks you. However, I had to remove the tick from the "Enable zero crossing detection" in the If block options

Comment: You're welcome, I think this setting is simulation/solver dependent and sometimes it's necessary to switch it off.